# Simple HTML that comes out looking way off?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I cannot for the life of me figure out why my table is turning out this way. The images and text should be lined up:

[image]

HTML:

```
<div id="items">
  <div class="category"><h1>Apparel</h1></div>
  <div class="list-product">
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td width="50" align="center" style="padding-right: 5px;">
        <img height="30" src="/images/products/none.jpg" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <img style="padding: 0 3px 0 0;" src="/images/icons/flag_red.png" />
      </td>
      <td valign="middle">
        <strong>Test Product</strong><br />
        <span style="color: #777;">This has a short description.</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
  ... and the other table here
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#items
{
width: 400px;
}

div.category
{
padding: 7px 13px;
background: #f0f0f0;
color: #101010;
font-size: 20px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
}

.list-product
{
border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
font-size: 12px;
padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer to your question (which is why I've just made it a comment) but have you considered not using tables for your layout?

Comment: I agree Chris, That's an awful lot of HTML there for such a simple layout. A HTML list would be much more appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add to Pete's answer, and to use the CSS rather than inline presentational-markup, you may want to try adding `vertical-align: middle` to the css for the table-cells.

As an afterthought, you may want to add a `line-height: 100px` (or however high your image is, plus a little padding) to your CSS for the cells containing the images, and specify `line-height: 50px` (50% of the line-height of the image cells) for the cells containing descriptive text, I'm not sure it'll work, but it sometimes works for centring text when `vertical-align` doesn't.

Comment: Turns out that my reset CSS file was applying "vertical-align: baseline;" to everything. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Might wanna try a valign on the TD tags. valign="middle" for all of them.

Answer (score 1):

try temporarily adding a border to the table so you can see where the image and text are getting aligned in their respective tds.  Also, do you need to use a span for the description text?

Answer (score 1):

What browser? I copy-pasted your HTML (added html & body tags), and copy-pasted your CSS (added head & style tags), and the vertical alignment is accurate -- doesn't match the problem in your picture.

Try adding a border to various elements, see if that sheds light on the crazy. And make sure you don't have typos between your code and the code pasted here.

Comment: Could I suggest using `background-color`s instead of `border`, as border tends to add to the height, sometimes further distorting the layout.

Comment: Touché. I think I'll adopt that myself. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a CSS reset file? This looks like a CSS thing to me. Maybe line-height?

I'm not sure it matters, but I would switch from using the break and span to using heading and paragraph tags and then just style those.

```
  <td valign="middle">
    <h2>Test Product</h2>
    <p>This has a short description.</p>
  </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a fixed width for your table, and each td tag.  You have the width of the table set to 100%, and a fixed width on the first tag.  The second and third td tags are adjusting based on the content within the td tags to fill the 100% width on the table tag.